# Metadata in separate file does not display as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am trying to add my metada in separate file in order to keep my models as clean as posiblen but something seems to be wrong becuase now it seems that some properties do not display the validation.Here is my model clasS:

```
public partial class BookModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set;}
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string BookUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my metada partial class:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(BookModel))]
public partial class BookModelMetada
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string BookUrl { get; set; }
}
```

The wierd field is that the PublicationDate and Price display the validation error but the other properties do not.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

View Code:

```
 <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Book.Name, "Book Name")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Book.Name)
        </p> 
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Book.Author)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Book.Author)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Book.PublicationDate ,"Publication Date")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Book.PublicationDate, new { @class="datepicker" })
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Book.Price)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Book.Price)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Book.CategoryId, "Select category")
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Book.CategoryId, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name"))
        </p>
        <p> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Book.Description)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Book.Description)
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="link"/>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Books", "ProductManager", null, new { @class = "link" })
        </p>
```

Comment: What does your View look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I added `[MetadataType(typeof(BookModel))]` on the metada class instead of the model class.

Answer (score 0):

There can be one or more causes:
But at first make sure that you included jquery.unobtrusive and jquery.validate in the view or in the layout of the view.
Your View however seems to be unclear, you have to use `@Html.LabelFor(model =>model.Book.Author)`. Please post your full view.